# Removing Line From Python List - All Lines Containing Certain Number

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am looking to remove lines from a list that have a 0 in the 4th position. When I write out the file now it is not eliinating all the zero lines.

```
counter = 0
for j in all_decisions:
    if all_decisions[counter][4] == 0:
        all_decisions.remove(j)
    counter += 1

ofile = open("non_zero_decisions1.csv","a")

writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')

for each in all_decisions:
    writer.writerow(each)

ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
all_decisions = [x for x in all_decisions if x[4] != 0]
```

Or, use `filter`.

```
all_decisions = filter(lambda x: x[4] != 0, all_decisions)
```

The way you're doing this is not a good idea because you're modifying `all_decisions` while you're iterating over it. If you wanted to do it in a loop, I would suggest something like:

```
temp = []
for x in all_decisions:
    if x[4] != 0:
        temp.append(x)
all_decisions = temp
```

But this is basically just a more verbose equivalent of the list comprehension and `filter` approaches I showed above.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your loop which eliminates the lines:

```
counter = 0
for j in all_decisions:
    if all_decisions[counter][4] == 0:
        all_decisions.remove(j)
    counter += 1
```

If you remove an element, you *also* bump the counter. The consequence of that is that you're skipping lines. So you might miss lines to be removed. Try only bumping the counter if you didn't remove an element, i.e.

```
counter = 0
for j in all_decisions:
    if all_decisions[counter][4] == 0:
        all_decisions.remove(j)
    else:
        counter += 1
```

That being said, a more concise way to do what you want would be

```
with open("non_zero_decisions1.csv","a") as ofile:
  writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
  writer.writerows(d for d in all_decisions if d[4] != 0)
```

The `with` clause will take care of calling `close` on `ofile` after executing the code, even if an exception is thrown. Also, `csv.writer` features a `writerows` method which takes a list of rows. Thirdly, you can use a generator expression `d for d in all_decisions if d[4] != 0` to replace your filtering loop.